# randomness in a time series

Tags: r, time-series

how can I introduce randomness into a daily time series? what are my options?

```
dataset = data.frame(days = as.Date(seq(from = as.Date("2021-01-01"),
                                        to   = as.Date("2025-12-31"), by = 1)),
                     obs  = rnorm(1826, mean = 1, sd = 2))
```

Although this time series was created with rnorm, I have a daily dataset of observed values.

Comment: That's a bit vague. How much more randomness do you want?

Comment: What about adding noise to your data by doing `dataset$obs <- dataset$obs + rnorm(...)`?

Comment: Or are you looking for randomness in the spacing of the timeseries.

Comment: I think I found what I am looking, it should be something like a rnorm with limitations concerning the minimum and maximum value never <=0 and never above 1.9. should I just create a random vector using the rnorm and select a value that respects those limits??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sample with a given min or max, I'd go for sampling from a uniform distribution using `runif`. If this is not possible you could draw from a normal distribution and then cut off at the sides. However, it is not trivial for the mean and sd of the truncated sample to remain equal to those you specified in `rnorm`. In addition, the normal distribution doesn't really have a min and a max, although the probability becomes small at large distances.

This R-Help thread provides some good pointers for generate numbers from a normal distribution with a min and a max:

http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/how-to-generate-a-normal-distribution-with-mean-1-min-0-2-max-0-8-td3481450.html

This suggest that generating lots of numbers and truncating is a bad solution, and inefficient.